# Using headScript view helper for <head> and <body> scripts

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework

I've got some scripts I'd like to add to the end of the `<body>` of the page, and some that I need to have in the `<head>`. I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to add certain scripts to the `<head>` and certain in the `<body>` using a segment or something like that. Say I have two scripts that are going to go in the body:

```
$this->view->headScript()->prependFile($assetUrl . "/js/jquery.min.js");
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile($assetUrl . "/js/application.js");
```

And I want this one in the `<head>` instead:

```
$this->view->headScript()->prependFile($assetUrl . "/js/modernizr.min.js");
```

Calling `$this->headScript();` outputs all three in both cases. Is there a way to group scripts? I could just paste the HTML snippet manually, but I'd like to have it in code because I switch to minified versions of the javascript if the site is running in the production environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I'd make my own helper called `htmlScript`. You should be able to extend the existing `headScript` helper, overriding the registry key property only.</strike>

Then just echo out your helper in your layout at the end of the document

```
<?php echo $this->htmlScript() ?>
```

**Edit** Been out of the loop for too long ;)

There's already a helper for you - [Zend_View_Helper_InlineScript](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.inlinescript)

Comment: Guess I have as well. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

If you want to override the script files:

```
$this->view->headScript()->setFile()
```

*EDIT* I'm not sure why I got downvoted. I gave an alternative answer to your question, albeit succinctly. If you have prepended/appended two script files, but for a specific controller or module you wish to override the loading of those scripts with a third, then setFile should do exactly what you asked.

Comment: You should read the question. Wasn't asking for how to override the script files.